# cross browser resizable button glitch

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

http://jsfiddle.net/KKL5G/

Please take a look at the above html and css for the buttons.

The span that is used to show the right part of the button shifts 1px downwards on these browsers. Works correctly as expected on Firefox.

Windows: IE8, Opera, Safari
Mac: FF, Safari, Opera, Chrome

UPDATE 1] The bug is visible even in Firefox 11.0 windows randomly while changing the height of the window.

To reproduce it go to the jsfiddle link mentioned above and try to resize the result's frame.. you might see the span flickering... 
[Edit 2: Actually i was resizing the firebug panel in windows firefox when i noticed the jumping span in the right side of the button, earlier i thought it worked fine in firefox.]

I have also tried an all inline elements example.
http://jsfiddle.net/sbWCD/

P.S. The this simple image is just a placeholder for some more complex design, am not looking for a CSS3 solution..

Comment: Shifts down 1px in Firefox 11 on Ubuntu. Will look into solution in a second.

Comment: Why do you split the button in two elements?

Comment: Why aren't you using `background-color:` with some rounded corners for newer browsers? You're fantastically overcomplicating the problem, and introducing new ones.

Comment: @jamwaffles The round corners are a requirement. Also you are forgetting old browsers don't support css3 border-radius. css3 cannot reproduce complex designs or patterns which images can.

Comment: I know full well that older browsers don't support CSS 3, hence my "rounded corners **for newer browsers**". Non support for older browsers doesn't detract from the usability of a site, and very little from it's design in this context. A solid background colour is _not_ a complex design, unless you're using it as a placeholder for something more complex in your example, in which case you should say so.

Comment: The example in the question specifically used images.. Thought those who really understood the problem would be interested in why the span behaves. I appreciate the css3 suggestions but i am trying to find the cause of this specific problem. and yes the image used in the example is a placeholder for something more complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is way too complicated for what you want to achieve.
Here's a cleaned up version http://jsfiddle.net/KKL5G/4/
It should work cross-browser.

Using `border-radius`, it's easy to make boxes with rounded corners and there is no need for a background-image.

Comment: Sorry the background image is a requirement, I plan to change the image later, for which css substitute is not possible..

Answer (score 0):

Hmm i adjusted the vertical padding of the  to total the height up to 32px and changed the line-height to 33px on the span.l in the example with span and it now seems to be working in firefox and safari.

http://jsfiddle.net/sbWCD/3/

Works but still no clue what caused the problem.